# jQuery keypress() - get all chars until enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keyup

I'm trying to create a keypress/keyup function which reads from the document (not from an input field) - I'm gonna use it for a barcode scanning device.

### function

```
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      var barcode = e.which;
      // the barcode should be without the enter at the end

      if (e.keyCode == 13){
         // stop reading 
      }
    });
```

I'm quite new to javascript and jQuery - as you probably already noticed.

Thanks for every help!

## Update

This worked for me:

```
    $(function(){

            var barcode = '';

            var getCode = function (e) {
                if (e.which != 13) {
                    barcode += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                } else {
                    $(document).unbind('keyup', getCode);
                    console.log(barcode);
                }
            };

            $(document).on('keypress', getCode);

            // Barcode ausgeben


            // Produktinfos ausgeben
            $('span#articleID').text('articleID');
            $('span#productName').text('productName');

        });
```

Thanks all!!

Comment: so what's the problem ?

Comment: I don't know how to stop the function and end with the variable "barcode" being only the barcode - without the enter. And it should also be unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to bind on keyup. When enter is pressed, just unbind the function to make sure the code won't change anymore.

```
var barcode = '';

var getCode = function (e) {
    if (e.which != 13) {
        barcode += e.which;
    } else {
        $(document).unbind('keyup', getCode);
        console.log(barcode);
    }
};

$(document).on('keyup', getCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```js
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         console.log("Stopped");
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
     } else {
        var barcode = e.which;
     // the barcode should be without the enter at the end
         $("#dvStatus").append("</br> " + e.key + " Key should be logged");
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvStatus">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var BarCodeStr='';

document.onkeydown=function(e){

if (e.keyCode===13) {ProcessBarCodeStr(); BarCodeStr='';} else {BarCodeStr=BarCodeStr+e.keyCode;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider instead removing the newline character (\n). In this case, you'd be looking for:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  //check for different types of newlines
  var barcode = e.which.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

  if (e.keyCode == 13){
     // stop reading 
  }
});
```